# Will code completion in .js files work using atom-typescript plugin for atom?

Tags: javascript, typescript, atom-editor

I have a typescript definition file https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/arcgis-js-api/arcgis-js-api.d.ts. I used atom-typscript plugin in atom editor and was able to get code completion in .ts files when I use import/require. How can I get code completion work in .js files (in amd)? is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get code completion work in .js files (in amd)? is it possible?

Not using atom-typescript. VSCode and WebStorm supports providing intellisense for `.js` files using `.d.ts` files.

It's requested but not on the plans for atom-typescript : https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/issues/315